# Form builder schema for SQL database?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, optimization, schema

There are many ways one can envision the solution, from the top of my head:

- Two table approach:

  - `Field` table with `(name, field_name, type, description, meta)` attributes
  - `Form` table with `(name, created_by)` [name being foreign-key]
- Code-generation approach:

  - New tables created on the fly

Example of what will come in from the user (e.g.: via an `HTTP POST`):

```
{
    "name": "dinner_time",
    "fields": [
        {"field_name": "hungry", "type": "boolean", "description":"", "meta": [""]]},
        {"field_name": "time", "type": "datetime", "description":"time now", "meta": [""]]}
    ],
    "created_by": "AT"
}
```

How should I enable this use-case, and what should I be extra wary about?

Comment: Unfortunately this is something relational databases are really quite bad at. Dynamic user-defined data with variable structure. Defining the form structure is only half your problem; where it gets ugly is storing the form results. I'd seriously consider just using `json` representation all the way through, whether with PostgreSQL's json support or using a different product that might be better suited to variable-structured data.

Comment: But that'd result in a huge performance hit. Let's say a form is created, and millions of submissions against it are recorded. Without indices and other db features, answering aggregate and even simple `SELECT` queries would become really inefficient. I'm not talking about exposing a whole `Microsoft Access`-esque interface, but a simple form builder (with PK, FK and indexes) shouldn't be nontrivial to create.

Comment: I agree it *shouldn't* be hard. As I said it's an area RDBMSes pretty much suck at. If you aren't doing lots and lots of different forms you could create tables with dynamically app-generated schemas. This doesn't tend to scale well to tens of thousands of forms (tables) though.

Answer (score 0):

It's doable and quite safe approach is

- Store form definitions in `form_type` table with JSONB and proper indexing. The table should have a marker telling if the form is already SQL-ized with `create table`
- Write a asynchronous processing tool (cron worker) which will update table structure and issue proper CREATE TABLE requests, marking `form_type`as deployed to SQL
- form submit requests can be issued only after the form table is deployed
- you can and should limit permissions / quota for this deployment task

Why async? I would avoid doing this in trigger due to locking issues under high load. Also, easy to DDOS so permissions should be separate for form insert and form create.

Comment: Thanks @filiprem ; I've been thinking of this, is there a way of faking the entity `SELECT`/`UPDATE`/`INSERT` operates on to be a generic JSONB? - Fallback instead of `relation "a" does not exist`; then later data can be migrated into real tables that are created asynchronously and drained/pulled asynchronously…